# Playing the appropriate sound when hovering over a link

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

Context: This is a Youtube API javascript and iframe that plays the sound of the youtube link when you hover over the link. The link is inputted into a table just so you know.

Problem: The problem is that when I hover over a link that I input into the table i.e say I put multiple links (each connected to a different sound) in the table but when I hover over each link they only play the sound of the first link in the table; The other links in the table does not play their appropriate sounds. Can someone help me modify the code below to fix this issue?

HTML (Iframe the src is customized to play that particular link):

```
<div class="clickme">
    <iframe id="existing-iframe-example" width="300" height="200" allow="autoplay"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{-list[1]-}}?autoplay=1&mute=0&enablejsapi=1"
    frameborder="0" style="display: none">                                   
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript(Youtube API):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
        tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player1;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player1 = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example', {
                playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            document.getElementById('existing-iframe-example').style.borderColor = '#FF6D00';
            event.target.playVideo();
        }



        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            //changeBorderColor(event.data);
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                //var myFetchedNextVideoId = document.getElementById('clickme');
                player1.seekTo(0);
                player1.playVideo();
                //player1.loadVideoById(myFetchedNextVideoId);

            }
            //if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) {
            //    player.loadVideoById(myFetchedNextVideoId);
            //}
        }


        // Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
        // A $( document ).ready() block.

             $(document).ready(function () {
                 console.log("ready!");
                 var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("clickme");
                 for (i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
                     var list = menu[i];

                     var link = String(list.outerHTML)
                     if (link.includes('youtube')) {

                         list.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (event) {
                            
                             console.log('mouse enter ');
                             player1.playVideo();

                         });
                         list.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (event) {
                             
                             console.log('mouse out ');
                             player1.pauseVideo();
                         });


                     }

                 }
        });




    </script>
```

Comment: The HTML is missing all of the `.clickme` elements -- it's important to know how HTML is structred because hovering behavior depends on the mouse's position within and outside of it.

Comment: I have added the clickme class

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you initialize only the first player with your `var player1`, but you need to initialize a player for each of your videos. You should use your id in iframe only once, I recommend you to use the youtube-video-id as id, but you can choose whatever you want. Give your iframe a classname, e.g. `videoPlayer` and then you can initialize all your players:

```
function createVideoElement(videoContainer) {
    const videoID = $(videoContainer).data('youtube-id');
    new YT.Player($(videoContainer).attr('id'), {
        videoId: videoID,
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
    });
}

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    $('.videoPlayer').each(function(index, videoContainer) {
        createVideoElement(videoContainer);
    });
}
```

Your HTML for the iframe could look like this, the JavaScript should fill in the iframe code:

```
<div class="videoPlayer" data-youtube-id={{-list[1]-}}></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the modified iframe and javascript code based on what you mean please?

Comment: Can you modify this please?

Comment: Can someone help me with this person's answer please?

Comment: I don't understand - the modified code is in my answer? You don't need the iframe html because the javascript snippet will load the iframe. Which part doesn't work as expected for you?

Comment: For example, provide the modified code for functions onPlayerReady() and onPlayerStateChange() along with an example for what you meant with the iframe.